# Mousewheel interaction with slider revolution

Tags: wordpress, revolution-slider

We use Slider Revolution v 5.x on our website. The issue is that we cannot navigate to the bottom of our site using the mouse wheel if the mouse pointer is over the slider. The interaction of the mouse with the slider is useful but in our case with the full-screen slider, it will force the user to use the keyboard or click on the thin scrollbar to navigate inner the page. My question is where can we disable this functionality of Rev Slider? We are lost in all of these options that Rev Slider allow.
Thank you in advance. :)

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your Revolution slider options

```
{
....
  navigation: {
...
      keyboardNavigation: "off",//enable or disable keybored navigation
      mouseScrollNavigation: "off", //enable or disable mouse scroll navigation
....
  },
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the mouse interaction with the slider by the following setting of Slider Revolution. See the Image Attached
[Click-to-View-Screen-Shot-Of-Setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2jz3F.png)

Comment: If you have multiple people working on the same slide (not simultaneously but in shifts), does this setting affect everyone, or is it relative to each user?

Comment: @AsIf basically this is the default setting for the slider and when you have set up it so after that whenever a new user comes to change anything on the slide will get the updated slider details so and must be working.
These are navigation options which you can set and those will work for the whole website and all users.